# Plotting/changing shapes of Kmeans clusters based on a categorical column python/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I have a dataframe DF which looks like this:

```
    col1 col2 col3         test_results
    (Some discrete values) Ok
                           Ok
                           NOK
                           Finished
     .....                 NOK
```

Now i have applied PCA on this to reduce the dimensions which will be a numpy Array called reduced_cr after this I applied KMeans and found 3 cluster solution as the best solution and plotted the clusters as follows:

```
  plt.scatter(reduced_cr[:,0],reduced_cr[:,1],c=km_3_new.labels_,cmap='Spectral',alpha=0.5)
  plt.show()
```

But now i want to change the shape of these scatters based on the categorical column test_results from my DF.The problem here is my reduced_cr is a numpy array so i cannot use this to change the shape of the scatters or is it possible?

Other way i thought is somehow using the cluster labels so i have added a column for cluster labels to my DF as 'cluster_3' is it possible to plot the clusters as well as change the shape of the clusters based on the categorical column test_results

Answer (score 0):

Does this plotting procedure, where each group is plotted separately with its own parameters, answer your question? I don't have your data so I just invented data and group indices (in your question km_3.labels). You can use your labels as indices, as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generating some data:
reduced_cr = np.random.rand(5,2)

# generating indices (you'll use K-means groups):
inds1 = [0,2]
inds2 = [1,3,4]

plt.scatter(reduced_cr[inds1,0], reduced_cr[inds1,1],cmap='Spectral',alpha=0.5,marker='o')

plt.scatter(reduced_cr[inds2,0], reduced_cr[inds2,1],cmap='Spectral',alpha=0.7,marker='+', c='r')
```

EDIT:  To get the inds from a list of labels you can do something like this:

```
label = ['OK','OK','Finished','NOk','OK','NOk'] # inventing labels, I don't have your data
colordict = {'OK': 'red', 'NOk': 'blue', 'Finished': 'green'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i in range(3):
     inds = [j for j, x in enumerate(label) if x == label[i]]
     ax.scatter(reduced_cr[inds,0], reduced_cr[inds,1], c = colordict[label[i]])
```

Comment: But where are you considering my categorical column test_run_results?

Comment: inds1 and inds2 can be build based on the categories. Each one denotes the rows belonging to one category. If you provide data and/or give specific examples of your vars it will be easier to write a more precise code for your needs. But the general idea is that you can plot each category (after getting its indices) in a different plot command with its own parameters (e.g. marker kind, color, alpha value)

Comment: I am really sorry I am Facing difficulty in understanding this. I have made an edit to my question. Can you please check if that is helpful?

Comment: Please provide a small amount of data, this would be easiest. I don't even know if you're using pandas DataFrame for your data, numpy matrix...  But in any event what you're missing is finding the indices (rows numbers in your data matrix) for each group: what row numbers are OK, what are the row numbers for NOk, and what rows numbers are Finished. These are the inds1 and inds2 I mentioned (you'll also have inds3). For example, NOk appears on rows 4,6,12,14,43 and 60. These are your indices for NOk and you'll plot them together in one scatter command as above. Then move to the next one...

Comment: I have re framed the whole question This should help I guess.

Comment: Look, we still do not have your data... How do clustering results look like? What is km_3_new? How does it look like? Your question is about plotting and I have to guess your clustering technique... But still, let me try to edit my response, it will include a part of mapping labels from a list into indices and then plotting.

Comment: This is where i am fitting my model km_3_new=KMeans(n_clusters=3,random_state=123).fit(reduced_cr). Km_3_new.labels gives which data point goes to which group. Now where you have used labels i should take my entire test_results column? Is it possible to change the shape of the labels instead of color?

Comment: Yes and yes :) Instead of labeling 'OK', 'NOk'... you can take the clustering labels (I see they're numeric but it's the same idea). And yes, as in my response above, marker='o' or marker='+' (and others) are possible, instead of colors. Play with these things. And see help for the scatter function (type plt.scatter?)